# Does html5 canvas support hex colors with alpha?

Tags: javascript, canvas, hex

I was wondering If a square could be drawn in color `#FF000000` then a circle inside of `#00000000`?

This would be as drawing a square with black pixels then drawing over a circle with transparent pixels.

As I understand hexadecimal colors basic are red, green, blue, but it looks like you can have a similar format as `rgba` but like `argb` in hex with `00` being totally transparent and `FF` being solid.

It makes sense as in a png when you can have transparent pixels that the alpha value should also translate to the hex as a legitimate and manipulative value.

Hex colors with 8 characters don't seem standard at all though (normally 6 long) as I have first seen them today on an android app and was wondering if they are (with want of better wording - please edit if unclear) legit.

Is this a legit color `#00000000`? It would be invisible but black where-as this would be as I understand solid black: `#FF000000`;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** Modern browsers now support 8 character hex colors, for CSS and canvas.

---

Canvas, like CSS, does not support 8 character hex colors. You can however use the [`rgba` color syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba%28%29).

## Working Example:

```js
var cvs = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)';
ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: CSS in most of the latest browsers DOES support the 8 char hex colors like: `#00000080`

Answer (score 5):

You mentioned that you know hex colors can be broken up into r,g,b. one thing you could do would be to write a function that allows you to use 8-char hex codes:

```
function hex2rgba(hexa){
  var r = parseInt(hexa.slice(1,3), 16);
      g = parseInt(hexa.slice(3,5), 16);
      b = parseInt(hexa.slice(5,7), 16);
      a = parseInt(hexa.slice(7,9), 16)/255;
  return 'rgba('+r+', '+g+', '+b+', '+a+')';
}

ctx.fillStyle = hex2rgba('#aabbcc99');
//rgba(170, 187, 204, 0.59765625)
```

Comment: Thanks, that always gets me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`ctx.fillStlye = "#rrggbbaa"`

but it looks like crap and i have this problem i call staining where if i put a tint with this on a color it will not actauly turn that color and will have a tint of the old color and its really annoying bc i want it to fade full black but it wont. it gets worse the ,lower the alpha is (i think alpha will only stack a few times)
you should insted use

```
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.aa; //aa is in base 10 here! (its a scale from 1.0 to 0.0)
```